# Override build script for a dependency

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am building a Rust crate that has transitive dependencies on a few `*-sys` crates wrapping native libraries. The `*-sys` crates use `build.rs` to build the native libraries with cmake, which is not supported in my environment.

I already have those native libraries prebuilt elsewhere in my project tree. I would like to [override the build scripts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#overriding-build-scripts) to not run, and use the existing native libraries instead.

> If a manifest contains a links key, then Cargo supports overriding the build script specified with a custom library. The purpose of this functionality is to prevent running the build script in question altogether and instead supply the metadata ahead of time.
>
> To override a build script, place the following configuration in any acceptable Cargo configuration location.
>
> ```
> [target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.foo]
> rustc-link-search = ["/path/to/foo"]
> rustc-link-lib = ["foo"]
> root = "/path/to/foo"
> key = "value"
> ```

Source: [Cargo Reference > Build Scripts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#overriding-build-scripts)

My initial guess based on that documentation is that I would just need to add `rustc-link-lib` when declaring the dependency, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
[package]
# ...

[dependencies]
# ...
harfbuzz-sys = { version = "0.3", rustc-link-lib = ["harfbuzz"] }
# ...
```

Cargo still tries to invoke `build.rs` and fails.

Is there a correct way to override `harfbuzz-sys`'s `build.rs` for all of its transitive dependents in my project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the override information into one of the [Cargo configuration files](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html). For example for `harfbuzz-sys`, you could put this into `.cargo/config` inside your workspace:

```
[target.machine-vendor-os.harfbuzz]
rustc-link-search = ["/path/to/staging/usr/lib"]
rustc-link-lib = ["harfbuzz"]
```

Note that on the first line:

- `machine-vendor-os` must be the same as the value that you give to cargo with the `--target` option.
- `harfbuzz` must be the same as the `links` key defined in [your dependency's `Cargo.toml`](https://github.com/servo/rust-harfbuzz/blob/master/harfbuzz-sys/Cargo.toml#L14).

And on the second line, `/path/to/staging/usr/lib` is the path where your pre-compiled dependency is located on the build system.