# Compactly override a build script for all targets

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Expanding on an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54801479/) about [overriding build scripts with custom libraries](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#overriding-build-scripts)...

I have multiple build targets, and might have more in the future:

`.cargo/config`:

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.libfoo]
rustc-link-lib = ["libfoo"]

[target.x86_64-apple-darwin.libfoo]
rustc-link-lib = ["libfoo"]

# ...
```

Say I am overriding the library "libfoo" with the same prebuilt library for all targets. How would I avoid having to list out `[target.<machine-vendor-os>.libfoo]` tables for all current and future targets? Is there a `cfg(...)` expression that would achieve this?

Comment: I'm unwilling to post this as an answer, because I can't test it - but does `[target.'cfg(all())'.libfoo]` work? `all()` is truthy when the bracket contents are empty.