# How do I prevent build-scripts of dependencies to run?

Tags: rust, build-script

My setup consists of a SQL database, a Rust library to access that database, and a Rust gui to display the data. The library contains a build.rs script that generates the schema.rs file for the SQL database. It does so using the diesel_cli (because I have not found a smarter way to do that). This means that having diesel_cli installed is a requirement to build the library. I recently decided to split gui and library into separate packages. The gui now refers to the library as a dependency via git URL.

Locally everything builds as expected. My github pipeline of the gui however fails with a panic in the build script of the library, because it does not have diesel_cli installed. I am pretty confident that the build script was not run when I built the gui locally.

In an attempt to fix this I checked the environment variable containing the package name, to only run the content of the build script when building the library, but to no avail.

From the [Cargo book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#overriding-build-scripts):
"If a manifest contains a `links` key, then Cargo supports overriding the build script specified with a custom library. "

I think this refers to linking against a fully compiled binary. But I'm very happy to rebuild my library when building my gui. I just don't want to execute the code generation. So I do not think that this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54798172/override-build-script-for-a-dependency).

To summarise:

1. Why is the build script of the dependency run in the github action, but not locally? This is primarily to sate my curiosity.
2. How do I prevent the code generation of my dependency from running?
3. (Bonus) Is there a smarter way to generate the schema.rs file than calling diesel_cli in build.rs?

### Code

My build.rs in the library looks like this ("lorecore" is the library name):

```rust
extern crate cbindgen;

use std::{env, process::Command};

fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/api/c_api.rs");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=migrations/");

    if env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME") != "lorecore" {
        return;
    }

    let crate_dir = env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap();

    // Generate C header file
    cbindgen::Builder::new()
        .with_crate(crate_dir)
        .with_no_includes()
        .with_language(cbindgen::Language::C)
        .generate()
        .expect("Unable to generate C header file.")
        .write_to_file("lorecore_api.h");

    // Create dummy database
    let mut cmd = Command::new("diesel");
    cmd.arg("setup").arg("--database-url=dummy.db");
    cmd.output().expect("Failed to execute diesel migrations");
    // Create/Update schema.rs
    let mut cmd = Command::new("diesel");
    cmd.arg("print-schema").arg("--database-url=dummy.db");
    let schema = cmd.output().expect("Failed to execute diesel migrations");
    std::fs::write("src/sql/schema.rs", schema.stdout).expect("Failed to write schema.rs");
    // Delete dummy.db
    std::fs::remove_file("dummy.db").expect("Failed to delete dummy.db");

    // Call cargo fmt
    let mut cmd = Command::new("cargo");
    cmd.arg("fmt");
    cmd.output().expect("Failed to execute cargo fmt");
}
```

And here's my Cargo.toml from the gui, if that's of any importance:

```ini
[package]
name = "loregui"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
iced = { version = "0.10.0", features=["lazy"] }
iced_aw = { version = "0.7.0", default-features = false, features = ["card", "modal", "selection_list"] }
lorecore = { git = "https://github.com/TheComamba/LoreCore.git" }
preferences = {version = "1.1.0"}
rfd = "0.11.3" # file dialogs
```

The excerpt from my pipeline yaml file that gets executed is also pretty straightforward:

```yaml
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install dependencies for Linux
        if: matrix.os == 'ubuntu-latest'
        run: |
          apt-get update
          apt-get install -y sudo curl build-essential cmake pkg-config libfontconfig1-dev cargo
          ./scripts/install_build_dependencies_linux.sh

      - uses: dtolnay/rust-toolchain@stable

      - uses: clechasseur/rs-cargo@v1
        if: ${{ !inputs.isRelease }}
        with:
            command: build
```

Comment: Your build script probably doesn't run on your local machine because you instructed cargo to rerun it if the files from which the schema is generated change (otherwise, it's useless to regenerate them). Since you probably have already generated those files, Cargo is "smart" and doesn't run the build script again; but in the CI, those files are not generated yet so it does call the build script.